# C++ slow lambda function performance (observed during sort)

Tags: c++, sorting, lambda

I observe a noticable performance penalty when using lambda for a comparator function in C++ sort. Tried:

```
// vector<int> F(N);
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    idx[i] = i;
sort(idx.begin(), idx.end(), [F](int x, int y) {
    if (F[x] < F[y])
        return true;
    if (F[x] == F[y])
        return (x < y);
    return false;
});
```

Basically the intent is to sort F, but have the original indices available after sort. The above code is slow. The fast solution is:

```
vector<pair<int,int>> tmp(N);
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    tmp[i] = {F[i], i};
sort(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
```

I wonder why my g++ is so slow with the lambda version. (I used optimized compiles.)

Edit. A bird in the comments, I invited passing by reference. I considered deleting my post, but there are some insightful answers below.

Comment: You’re capturing `F` by value rather than by reference, which makes a duplicate copy of the vector. Perhaps that’s contributing to the runtime?

Comment: Change `[F]` to `[&]`

Comment: Thanks, my faith in the compiler is back. My mistake omitting the &. I will delete the question in an hour unless there is an objection. (One wonders why have pass by value for a vector at all. Is there a use case for that?)

Comment: @Matyas The compiler doesn't know it's a vector, only that it is a class-valued parameter. If very small it makes a lot of sense to pass it by value.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments you can use `[&F]` to capture the vector by reference.
Alternatively, if the standard allows (at least `c++14`) you could use a move clause in the capture list: `[F = std::move(F)]`